# HBase operations hang when nodes go offline

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I noticed that operations like Put hang forever if nodes go offline (server crash e.g.)

Here's the relevant logs from the client:

> (AsyncProcess.java:1777) - Left over 1 task(s) are processed on
> server(s): [s1.mycompany.com,16020,1519065917510,
> s2.mycompany.com,16020,1519065918510,
> s3.mycompany.com,16020,1519065917410]
>
> (AsyncProcess.java:1785) - Regions against which left over task(s) are processed: [...]

In my case, s2 and s3 went offline. (p.s. ~50 nodes in cluster)

Shouldn't this problem be handled by HBase? E.g. if region servers go offline, their regions are reassigned to other servers and puts change their destination?

Since HBase is fault tolerant, this problem should not happen

Comment: If the Dataset is skewed onto a machine that falls offline, how would its data be reassigned?

Comment: @cricket_007 idk, client sends put to machine, it crashes, client retries from the beginning (asking ZK where put should be sent). I think it's a base scenario for distributed storage